# tensorflow: how to get image or sample id?

Tags: tensorflow

I have encountered a problem for mnist dataset on tensorflow. As you probably know, using batches it does not preserve order on datasets but I need to know exactly which image of the samples I am working on. Does TF have any kind of indicator such as ID or some information that tells you which images it has extracted? For instance in one batch we may get images 20,1,4,6 and in another we get 3,7,88 etc from mnist. I want to have access to these IDs, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add your own indication; when you enqueue the features and labels you can enqueue the indicator as well.